# CSS Control dimensions/positioning of rotated text

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML code as

```
<div class="fl">
<div class="titleTextV">My ABC</div>
</div>
```

Now I have applied the CSS to rotate text as;

```
.titleTextV{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    font-size:1.3em;
    background:#999;
    height:100%;
}
```

I want this titleTextV class to span the entire height of its
 container 100%, no px value and be positioned inside, but currently the text is moving out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you user jQuery try this:

```
$('.fl').height($('.titleTextV').width());
```

And add `display: inline-block;` to your `titleTextV` class.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/YC8RB/4/) at jsFiddle:

Comment: Thx a lot..If I see the demo in FF, it is not taking the width exactly, while in IE, the width is correct but the container does not stretch..